# C++ chrono::system_clock::now() vs time(0)

Tags: c++

is there any significant difference between the `chrono::system_clock::now()` and `time(0)` functions, and their return value?

When should I use `chrono::system_clock::now()` instead of `time(0)`, and vice versa ?

Comment: Question is opinion based. But for C++ I'd say use std::chrono for anything related to time. time() is kind of the "C" left over.  You might also find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182781/what-are-the-advantages-of-stdchrono-compared-to-the-legacy-time-library#:~:text=std%3A%3Achrono%20offers%20a,constraints%20on%20a%20modern%20system. Note that chrono isn't young any more and even got updates in C++20

Comment: `time` only returns seconds, chrono should be more precise

Answer (score 2):

### `system_clock::now()` vs `time(0)`

- `system_clock::now()` and `time(0)` measure the same thing:  [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). This is unspecified by `time(0)`, but true in practice.  It is also unspecified by `system_clock::now()` in C++11/14/17, but true in practice.  [In C++20 it is specified by `system_clock::now()`.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1)
- The precision (seconds, microseconds, whatever) reported by `system_clock::now()` and `time(0)` is unspecified.  For `system_clock`, the precision can be discovered by your application, either at compile time or run time.  For `time(0)`, the precision must be read by a human from the documentation.  The typical precision for `time(0)` is seconds.  For LLVM on Apple OS's, the precision of `sytem_clock::now()` is microseconds.  On gcc/Linux, nanoseconds.  And on Windows <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10</sub> of a microsecond.  Because of the design of `<chrono>` it is easy to write portable code that does not change with the underlying precision.
- The range of `time(0)` is unspecified, and on 32 bit machines typically about +/-68 years centered on 1970 (2038 is coming up fast...).  On 64 bit machines the range of `time(0)` is +/-292 billion years.  The range of `system_clock::now()` is discoverable at compile-time or run-time and is never less than +/-292 years (centered on 1970).  The finer the precision, the smaller the range.
- The return type of `time(0)` is typically a signed integral type, which runs the risk of being confused with all of the other integral types in your application (no type safety).  The return type of `system_clock::now()` is a class type that has the semantics of a time point.  It can not be confused with integral or floating point types.  It is a distinct type from a time duration.  Misuses of this time point in illogical ways are caught at compile time (strong type safety).
- `time(0)` interoperates with the rest of the [date/time library](https://cigix.me/c17#7.27) in `<time.h>`.
- `sytem_clock::now()` interoperates with the rest of the [date/time library](http://eel.is/c++draft/#time) in `<chrono>`.  This includes conversions to and from `time_t` returned by `time(0)`.  In C++11/14/17, calendrical and time zone functionality does not exist, but can be added on by free, open-source libraries.<sup>1</sup>  In C++20, full calendrical and time zone support exists within `<chrono>`.

---

<sup>1</sup> E.g.: [Howard Hinnant's date/time library.](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)